# Asp Net C# Sslstream Alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, 3270

I'm using .net 1.1 and I can't upgrade.

Is there some alternative (in .net 1.1) to connect a client to a mainframe 3270 using SSL?  just with .net 1.1 libraries or cs files without installing anything?

I tried the open3270 library and I can connect without SSL. But when SSL is required, the connection is lost.

code from open3270 library that does not work...

```
 if (this.Config.UseSSL)
 {
   NetworkStream mNetworkStream = new NetworkStream(socketBase, false);                     
 SslStream ssl = new SslStream(mNetworkStream, false, new                      RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(cryptocallback));
        ssl.AuthenticateAsClient(this.address);
        this.socketStream = ssl;
 }
```

...

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why can't you use .NET 2.0? I can't think of a single situation where you would be using 1.1 and you could not use 2.0?

Comment: The company where I work is stuck with some things. I hope they will update some day, but for now I have to use the .net 1.1. I am not the admin of the server, otherwise I'd be using a recent version.